# How count data group by two columns in multi select

Tags: mysql

I am trying get scans performed by employees at 3 stations and finally count them.
I have two tables:

*employees tab*

```
user_id|first_name|last_name
```

*stats tab*

```
id|user_id|station|product_id
```

I would like to get this effect:

```
first_name|last_name|station1|station2|station3
_______________________________________________
John      |Doe      |2       |0       |5
```

First and last name can be combined into one cell

I have such a monster,but only for one employee :(

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT(m1.id) FROM stats m1 WHERE m1.user_id= :user_id AND m1.station=1) AS station1, 
   (SELECT COUNT(m1.id) FROM stats m1 WHERE m1.user_id= :user_id AND m1.station=2) AS station2, 
   (SELECT COUNT(m1.id) FROM stats m1 WHERE m1.user_id= :user_id AND m1.station=3) AS station3 
FROM stats m LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) (in your current approach), you can utilize Conditional Aggregation using `GROUP BY` on user, and joining the tables appropriately. It would be more *performant* as well:

```
SELECT 
  e.first_name, 
  e.last_name, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN m.station = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS station1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN m.station = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS station2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN m.station = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS station3
FROM stats m 
JOIN employees e ON e.user_id = m.user_id 
GROUP BY e.first_name, e.last_name
```

Above query will give you the result for all the employees (users). If you want the results only for a specific user, you can simply use the `WHERE` clause in it:

```
SELECT 
  e.first_name, 
  e.last_name, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN m.station = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS station1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN m.station = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS station2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN m.station = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS station3
FROM stats m 
JOIN employees e ON e.user_id = m.user_id 
WHERE e.user_id = :userid
GROUP BY e.first_name, e.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT first_name, last_name,
       count(case when station=1 then id) as station1,
       count(case when station=2 then id) as station2,
       count(case when station=3 then id) as station3
from stats inner join employees on employees.user_id=stats.user_id
group by first_name, last_name
```